# RPC is not working

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt2

i am new to gwt and trying to implement RPC .

on button click on HomePage

```
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

    /*  1.*/    cService.getRepositories(repocallback);
    //  2.  fService.getRepositories(repocallback);

        }
    });
```

1st one is working fine.

```
   (HomePage.java:195) 2012-03-01 14:29:45,988 [FATAL] Uncaught Exception:
 com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in     UmbrellaException#getCauses
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection     (BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.client.GUI.HomePage$7.onClick(HomePage.java:195)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:54)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

When i comment 1st and try to use 2nd its give s me error.

Initially i wrote all the methods in one class on the server side.. now i am making diffrent class and adding their methods which should related to them.

on server side 
1st class is for connection : which is working fine

2 class is for Folders with delete update add methods.

both the class extends RemoteServiceServlet.

i dont know whether i have to add something on web.xml , if there are two classes with "extends RemoteServiceServlet",

help me to solve my problem.
If neone need more details plz tell me , i will edit it.

edited_***_*_**

```
   public class FService implements FInterfaceAsync {


FInterfaceAsync service =(FInterfaceAsync)GWT.create(FInterface.class);

ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget) service;

public FService(){

    endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "folderService");
}



public void getRepositories(
        AsyncCallback<FCollection> repositoryCallback) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    service.getRepositories(repositoryCallback);
}
}
```

XML FIle

my WEB.xml is

```
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>CServlet</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>com.server.CServiceImpl</servlet-class> 
  </servlet> 

  <servlet> 
  <servlet-name>FServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.server.FServiceImpl</servlet-class> 
  </servlet> 

  <servlet-mapping> 
   <servlet-name>CServlet</servlet-name> 
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping> 

   <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>FServlet</servlet-name> 
       <url-pattern>/FServiceImpl</url-pattern> 
        </servlet-mapping>
```

CServlet is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved it was mistake in my coding.
I didnt initailize the FService with new FService();

```
    private static FService fService = new FService();
```

Answer (score 4):

Wild guess here, but it seems your `fService` might be null. How are you creating it? Are you using `GWT.create(FService.class);`?

By the way, yes, all your servlets (including the RPC ones) must be declared in `web.xml`.
Your remote service interface must also be annotated with `@RemoteServiceRelativePath("path")`.

EDIT: it seems `<url-pattern>/FilenetFolderServiceImpl</url-pattern>` in your `web.xml` should also be `/{moduleBaseURL}/folderService`, where `{moduleBaseURL}` is usually the name of your project (or similar).

Comment: yes i have used `GWT.create(FService.class);` i have edited n mentioned the service code.

Comment: @NewCodeLearner it seems correct, your problem might be elsewhere - have you debugged to make sure `fService` is not `null` in line 2 (`fService.getRepositories(repocallback);`)?

Comment: my project name is FCmis1.
somammping `<url-pattern>FCmis1/folderService</url-pattern>`
Still it is null.